# Луковая архитектура. Зависимость проектов, лежащих на одном слое

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, asp.net-core, зависимости

Не могу понять такую вещь: Луковая архитектура предполагает направленность зависимостей слоев к [центру](http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/chetanv/2015/07/06/understanding-onion-architecture/):

[image: направленность зависимостей в луковой архитектуре]

А что на счет зависимостей соседних проектов, лежащих во внешнем слое, то есть как-бы на одном слое?

К примеру, есть проект `ProductRepositoryTest` (Tests - Unit) в котором тестируется класс `ProductRepository` (Infrastructure - Repositories).

Картинка чуть изменится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это ведь нормально?**

Comment: Сам репозиторий точно тестироваться не должен. Он должен создаваться с помощью сторонней библиотеки, обеспечивающей хранение и извлечение сущностей.

Comment: @etki, а если мне необходимо создать _интеграционные тесты_, т. е.  если я хочу проверять правильно ли добавляются объекты в реальную БД?

Comment: В этом случае вы вероятнее всего будете тестировать сервис

Comment: @etki, так если репозиторий будет создан с помощью сторонней библиотеки, то мы посылаем к черту инверсию зависимостей и луковую архитектуру, потому что абстракции (наш домен) начинают зависеть от деталей (хранение данных), ведь интерфейс репозитория у нас должен находиться в центре. В итоге мы возвращаемся к классической слоеной архитектуре.